# Hide Navigation Links in VueJs When Clicked

Tags: vue.js

I tried everything to make the navigation links hide when I clicked but it didn't worked. Here my Header.vue file.

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar is-dark is-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <router-link to="/" class="navbar-item">
                 <img src="../../assets/logo.png" width="">
            </router-link>
            <a role="button"
                :class="{ 'is-active': ShowMenu }"
                class="navbar-burger burger"
                @click="toggleMenu()"
                aria-label="menu"
                aria-expanded="false">
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div :class="{ 'is-active': ShowMenu }"
            class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <router-link to="/" class="navbar-item">Home</router-link>
                <router-link to="/about" class="navbar-item">About</router-link>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-end">
                <div class="navbar-item">
                    <div class="field is-grouped">
                        <p class="control">
                            <router-link to="/login" class="button is-dark">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</span>
                            </router-link>
                        </p>
                        <p class="control">
                            <router-link to="/register" class="button is-light">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Register</span>
                            </router-link>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the JS codes. Navigation are working when a click the links but the only problem I have is that it didn't automatically hide.

```
export default {
  name: "Header",
  data() {
      return {
          ShowMenu: false,
          NavigationItems: true,
          NavigationItems: false
      }
  },
  methods: {
      toggleMenu: function() {
          this.ShowMenu = !this.ShowMenu
      },
      toggleNavItem: function() {
          false
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do have **NavigationItems** twice in the data property?

Comment: My first idea is that you should try **<button>** instead of **<a>** - the anchor tag may “eat” the click event. And the **toggleNavItem** method seems unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a v-if='!ShowMenu' role="button" ...
```

instead of using CSS

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `v-if` it will "kill" the element in the dom, but if you only want to toggle it use `v-show` width `!ShowMenu` like Steven explained.

And if you want to use a CSS class: do you have a class called `is-active` and is the default behavior of `.burger` `display: none;`? If you want to stay on this solution please provide us your CSS.

Comment: you can check my project here [link]http://buy-me.ml[/link], then try to click on the links on mobile view

Comment: i didn't use css